# Why Codota plugin in Eclipse is not working?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I downloaded and installed the Codota plugin for Eclipse following the given instructions, then i restarted eclipse. The problem is that Codota isn't really showing any suggestions when i'm coding how it's supposed to, even if the Codota icon in the down-right side of eclipse is saying that it's running normally. I tried going to Window > Preferences > Java > Editor > Content assist > Advanced and checked all the checkboxes for content assist, but nothing changed.
I'm using Eclipse Version: 2020-12 (4.18.0).

Edit:
I found out on codota.com/faq that you can trigger the suggestions manually by pressing ctrl+shift+spacebar, but for automatic suggestions this video on YouTube has the solution https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dTMgJEhraoc .

Comment: Their FAQ, https://www.codota.com/faq, suggests contacting them about any problems you run into. Unless you have error messages from the log or appearing in the UI, there's not much anyone can do here.

Comment: I will certainly do, thanks for replying!